Mathematica isn't returning identity matrix when multiplying matrix by its inverse
I'm trying to solve a coupled system of ODE's. I'm trying to decouple my equations by diagonalizing a matrix. Here's my code:
AA := -(β*Sin[θ] - (Cos[θ]/Sin[θ])*(1 + β*Cos[θ])); 
BB := 1 + β*Cos[θ]; 
CC := (1 + β*Cos[θ])/(β*Sin[θ]); 
DD := -((1 + 2*β*Cos[θ] + β^2)/(β*Sin[θ])); 
EE := -((Sin[θ]*(1 + β*Cos[θ])^2)/β); 
FF := D[AA, θ] - AA*CC - 1; 
GG := AA - DD; 
HH := D[BB, θ] - BB*CC; 
JJ := BB; 
KK := GG; 
LL := -EE; 
MM := JJ; 

M := Simplify[{{(-(1/GG))*(FF - (I*k)^2*((JJ*KK)/LL)), (-(1/GG))*(I*k*HH + I*k^3*((JJ*MM)/LL))}, {(-(I*k))*(KK/LL), k^2*(MM/LL)}}]; 
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[M]

Mathematica returns True for this code executed. Also, here, I is the complex number Sqrt[-1], not a constant or separate variable.
In the next bit I try to find a change of basis matrix P where M = P*D*Inverse[P]: 
In: Simplify[Eigensystem[M]]; 
egvals := Simplify[Eigensystem[M][[1]]]; 
egvecs := Simplify[Eigensystem[M][[2]]]; 
P := Transpose[egvecs]; 
Pinv := Inverse[Pmatrix]; 

In: Simplify[Pinv*P]

Out: {{((-β)*(-7 - 2*β^2 + 4*k^2*(2 + β^2))*Sin[θ] + 2*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(1 + 8*k^2 + 2*β^2 + 4*(1 + 2*k^2)*β*Cos[θ] + Cos[2*θ])*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])^2*Sin[θ]^2] + (2 + (8 - 12*k^2)*β^2)*Sin[2*θ] + 3*β*Sin[3*θ] + 2*β^3*Sin[3*θ] - 4*k^2*β^3*Sin[3*θ] + β^2*Sin[4*θ])/
    (4*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(1 + 8*k^2 + 2*β^2 + 4*(1 + 2*k^2)*β*Cos[θ] + Cos[2*θ])*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])^2*Sin[θ]^2]), 
   -((I*(β*(-7 - 2*β^2 + 4*k^2*(2 + β^2))*Sin[θ] + 2*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(1 + 8*k^2 + 2*β^2 + 4*(1 + 2*k^2)*β*Cos[θ] + Cos[2*θ])*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])^2*Sin[θ]^2] + 2*(-1 + (-4 + 6*k^2)*β^2)*Sin[2*θ] - 3*β*Sin[3*θ] - 2*β^3*Sin[3*θ] + 4*k^2*β^3*Sin[3*θ] - β^2*Sin[4*θ])^2)/
     (32*Sqrt[2]*(1 + 2*β*Cos[θ])^2*(k + k*β*Cos[θ])*Sqrt[(1 + 8*k^2 + 2*β^2 + 4*(1 + 2*k^2)*β*Cos[θ] + Cos[2*θ])*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])^2*Sin[θ]^2]))}, 
  {(I*Sqrt[2]*(1 + 2*β*Cos[θ])^2*(k + k*β*Cos[θ]))/Sqrt[(1 + 8*k^2 + 2*β^2 + 4*(1 + 2*k^2)*β*Cos[θ] + Cos[2*θ])*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])^2*Sin[θ]^2], 
   ((-β)*(-7 - 2*β^2 + 4*k^2*(2 + β^2))*Sin[θ] + 2*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(1 + 8*k^2 + 2*β^2 + 4*(1 + 2*k^2)*β*Cos[θ] + Cos[2*θ])*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])^2*Sin[θ]^2] + (2 + (8 - 12*k^2)*β^2)*Sin[2*θ] + 3*β*Sin[3*θ] + 2*β^3*Sin[3*θ] - 4*k^2*β^3*Sin[3*θ] + β^2*Sin[4*θ])/
    (4*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(1 + 8*k^2 + 2*β^2 + 4*(1 + 2*k^2)*β*Cos[θ] + Cos[2*θ])*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])^2*Sin[θ]^2])}}


What's going on here? Is my matrix secretly not diagonalizable?
My apologies for the difficulty of the expressions.

Assuming you mean
Pinv := Inverse[P]; 

(instead of Pmatrix, which is undefined) you need to use matrix mulitplication
Simplify[Pinv.P]    

which does give the identify. The symbol * is element-by-element multiplication.

wow I feel extremely unintelligent. sorry mate

Also, you might want to figure out the difference between := and =. Your expressions really should really be using = (instead of :=) and it will work much quicker as a result.
